# How to force Safari browser to disable icloud Keychain in member registration forms ?

Tags: html, safari, devexpress

We are developing an online hotel CRM system in DevEx environment and there is member registration form in our system.

Our customers said that there is a huge problem for their hotel customers when they try to sign up. As you may know in Safari Browser there is a icloud Keychain speciality to keep your most used password and automatically put that password while you try to fill registration form in browser. So if a hotel customer tries to register from safari browser and if they activated Keychain they can't enter their password into registration form.

What i need to know is how should i force safari browser to disable that Keychain speciality ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread: [Safari Keychain prevent with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960892/safari-keychain-prevent-with-html)

Seems there is a Jquery plugin which means all you have to do once you've added it is add the following to your input fields:

```
spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off"
```

There fore making your input fields look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden"  id="txtPass" name="txtPass" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text"  id="txtPass" name="txtPass" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
```

Link to the Jquery Plugin is here: http://plugins.jquery.com/disable-autocomplete/

But like I said you get more information in the previos thread I linked too.
Hope this helps