# avoiding the iCloud keychain in my web site

Tags: ios, safari, icloud, keychain

I've heard that Safari on iOS 12 will start backing up web passwords to the iCloud keychain, by default. My site does not trust cloud storage by default - how do I turn this off? Preferably in a way that allows the user to turn it back on, if they are more trusting than we are.

Searching for similar questions on this site, I found a couple ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604433/how-to-force-safari-browser-to-disable-icloud-keychain-in-member-registration-fo), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960892/safari-keychain-prevent-with-html)), but they deal with disabling autocomplete, not specifically with disabling cloud sharing.

Comment: I don't believe that ios12 safari stores passwords by default, but it does offer to users the opportunity to store passwords and use unique, strong passwords when a web site requests a new password. It is the user's decision as to whether they use these features, not yours. Arguably the keychain leads to better security; I don't even know a lot of my passwords since they are strong, unique and stored in the iCloud Keychain.  Passwords that aren't in the keychain tend to be weaker because I need to remember them.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, I'll double-check that.